# Present modalViewController in another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've implemented a facebook like slide menu. When I swipe the navigationBar, the "Settings" view will appear underneath.

The problem is when I try to present a modal view from the Settings view. I try to implement a feedback system (MFMailComposeViewController), but if I present it from the Settings view underneath, half of the modal view will be blocked by the overlay view (The rootView controller).

What can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

```
masterViewController = [[MatchTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"MatchTable" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Settings *sideMenuViewController = [[Settings alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil]; 

//  make sure to display the navigation controller before calling this
[MFSideMenuManager configureWithNavigationController:self.navigationController sideMenuController:sideMenuViewController];
```

Comment: Presenting a modalView from your window will solve the problem.Don't present it from any view.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How would I go about doing that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i did it like this to give it a sort of animation effect..You can choose any other effect you like:

```
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view cache:YES];
        [appDelegate.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:@"Your View Object"];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```